# Topology of Alexandroff

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set  $\mathbb{N \times N} $ with the lexicographic order topology (where the open elements are unions of  intervals of the form  $((a,b),(c,d))$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$). Is this space of Alexandroff (i.e. closed for  infinite intersections)?

I think that in fact it is of Alexandroff. i am not able to find a counterexample, but as would the proof.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $U_n = \{ ( 0, k ) : k > n \} \cup \{ (1,0) \}$.  Note that each $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb{N}^2_\text{lex}$, since it is the open interval between $( 0 , n )$ and $(1,1)$.  However the intersection $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n = \{ (1,0) \}$ is not open, since there is no "immediate predecessor" of $(1,0)$ in the lexicographic order.